# How to Resolve Runtime Error 6 when working with Arrays

Tags: excel, vba

I am building an array string which is converted into a percentage by dividing array values by a variable, which is `X`.

The problem I am facing is my array will sometimes return zero values for some of the array string values, which is causing an overflow on my code, it gets hung up on `Array Value / X` when the **Array Value = 0** & **X = 0**.
How can I modify my macro to skip dividing null or zero values?

Code

```
Sub buildMixChart(ByVal startdate As Date, ByVal endDate As Date)
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim arr() As Variant
Dim srs As Series
Dim cht As ChartObject
Dim ch As Chart
Dim axs As Axis
Dim x As Long

x = selectedDatesTotalCalls(startdate, endDate)

Set ws = Sheets("Analysis Report")
Set cht = Sheets("Analysis Report").ChartObjects.Add(Left:=225, Width:=800, Top:=530, Height:=150)
cht.Chart.ChartType = xlColumnClustered

With cht
Set srs = .Chart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries

    .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Interior.Color = RGB(232, 32, 118)
    .Chart.ApplyDataLabels
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.NumberFormat = "0%"
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Font.Name = "Arial"
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Font.Size = 12
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).DataLabels.Font.Bold = True
    .Chart.SeriesCollection(1).Format.Line.Visible = False
    .Name = "Portfolio Mix"
End With

For Each cht In ws.ChartObjects
Set ch = Sheets("Analysis Report").ChartObjects("Portfolio Mix").Chart
For Each axs In ch.Axes

    axs.HasMajorGridlines = False
    axs.Border.LineStyle = False

Next
Next cht

With ch.Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary)
    .Border.LineStyle = xlNone
    .MajorTickMark = xlNone
    .MinorTickMark = xlNone
    .TickLabelPosition = xlNone
End With

With ch
    .HasLegend = False
End With
Set ch = Nothing

With srs
    .Border.Color = vbWhite
    .XValues = Array("Client Interested", "Client Declined", "Appt", "Left VM", "Sent Letter", "Sent Email", "Unble to Rch", "Req. Call Later")

    'error happens here
    .values = Array(clientInterested(startdate, endDate) / x, clientDeclined(startdate, endDate) / x, clientAppt(startdate, endDate) / x, vmLeft(startdate, endDate) / x, letterSent(startdate, endDate) / x, emailSent(startdate, endDate) / x, unabletoReach(startdate, endDate) / x, reqCallLater(startdate, endDate) / x)
End With


  'remove the shape border
With ActiveSheet
    .Shapes("Portfolio Mix").Line.Visible = False
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Dividing by zero should be a *division by zero* error (11), not *overflow* (6). What needs to happen when `x` is `0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's quite a mouthful:

> ```
> .values = Array(clientInterested(startdate, endDate) / x, clientDeclined(startdate, endDate) / x, clientAppt(startdate, endDate) / x, vmLeft(startdate, endDate) / x, letterSent(startdate, endDate) / x, emailSent(startdate, endDate) / x, unabletoReach(startdate, endDate) / x, reqCallLater(startdate, endDate) / x)
> ```

Split it up; separate *computing the individual values* from *building an array of values*:

```
If x <> 0 Then
    Dim percentClientInterested As Double
    percentClientInterested = clientInterested(startdate, endDate) / x

    Dim percentClientDeclined As Double
    percentClientDeclined = clientDeclined(startdate, enddate) / x

    ...

End If
.values = Array(percentClientInterested, percentClientDeclined, ...)
```

That way if `x = 0` then the individual array elements will be `0` and you'll have valid data.

That said, dividing by zero should be throwing error 11 "division by zero", not error 6 "overflow". I suspect `x` is actually not `0`, but something pretty close; depending on what kind of `Array Value` we're looking at, dividing by a very small number could conceivably result in an overflow error.

Comment: your solution looks much cleaner and organized! Working great!

Comment: @Jose thanks, I'm still curious what kind of `x` we're looking at though - if `x` is legit between 0 and 1 and very close but not equal to 0, you still might hit an overflow error. In that case you need to decide on a threshold below which you treat `x` as being 0.